# next build error occrred from performace-relayer

Tags: next.js

next build occurred error by

```
ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/PATH/node_modules/next/dist/client/performance-relayer.js:1:135)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/PATH/node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:1:1406)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10) {
  type: 'ReferenceError'
```

I don't have any idea..

plz help

Comment: You have possibility to provide a code example? (https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-framework-46s4q)

Answer (score 4):

Generally, it happens because of incorrect import of NextJS components such as Link, router

For instance:

```js
import {router} from "next/client";   // will cause location not found error
```

will cause this type of error. The correct way is as follows:

```js
import router from "next/router";    // correct way
```

Same is with "Link":

```js
import Link from "next/link";    // correct way
```

Answer (score 2):

We had same problem. In our case, these were incorrect  imports of router:

```js
import { NextRouter } from "next/dist/client/router";
import { useRouter } from 'next/dist/client/router';
import { router } from "next/client";
```

I changed two first to **"next/router"** and replace the last one by using `useRouter()`

Answer (score 2):

**ReferenceError: location is not defined** is occurred due to the wrong import of next js package.

Suppose if you are using the router for routing pages using command push **router.push('/path')**,so we need to import router from **import {useRouter} from "next/router"** then use router like this :

```
const router=useRouter();

router.push('/path');
```

**Note:**
No need to import from "next/client"  like this:

```
import {router} from "next/client";
```

Next build error occurred from performance-relayer

I think it will solve your problem. Doc ref:- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router